# Пайплайн для веб разработки и администрирования

Tags: администрирование, centos, непрерывная-интеграция, wamp

Мне необходимо периодически обновлять php и другие пакеты на сервере (vps с centOS), администрировать сервер, разрабатывать фичи для joomla сайта. Бессрочно работаю один. Возможны конфликты версии joomla и php (они уже возникают при попытке всё обновить). Какой пайплайн посоветуете и почему?

В моём представлении, должны существовать инструменты для работы полной копии сервера, контроль версий на всём сервере и возможность быстро заменить прод на копию, но я не знаю, как такой найти или реализовать.

WAMP и аналоги, видимо, не подходят, т.к. устанавливается, во-первых, всё на windows, во-вторых, устанавливаются те версии пакетов, которые не стоят на моём боевом сервере.
На ум приходит идея создать виртуальную машину на centOS, но по какой-то причине не нахожу информации о том, что кто-то так делает, и это хорошая практика.

Comment: Обычно наблюдаю, что ставят staging и production сервера, то есть как минимум должен быть еще один сервер для тестирования "новых версий" будь то пакеты или новая версия кода.

Comment: Поддержу про `stage` и `prod`. Добавлю, что выкатывать изменения - лучше через систему управления конфигурации. Мне очень нравится `Ansible`.